# Design data structure for merging meeting schedules

Tags: data-structures

I was asked to design a data structure for the meeting schedules and after that to merge them. For example if person A has meeting from 9:00 AM to 10:00 AM and person B has meeting from 9:30 AM to 11:30 AM then the merged busy slot is from 9:00 AM to 11:30 AM.

I made the classes for the Person and this class has the collection of meeting objects. The Meeting  class has the start time [hh:mm] in 24 hours format so that I can do the comparison easily.

```
class Person {
String name;
Collection<Meeting> meetings;

}


class Meeting{
int hh, mm;
int duration; // duration will be in minutes from where we can get the end time. 
}
```

I want to know that which data structure  will be most efficient for merging. 
One way is to use the sorted ArrayList of meeting.

Any better design is appreciated.

Comment: Meetings of all persons should be merged to find busy intervals overall?

Comment: Yes. The outcome should have the busy slots as well as the free slots.  So that everyone can look at it and know what time is suitable to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Anonymouse suggested you can use 96 bits i.e. 12 bytes to represent a day so a 30 min meeting starting at 1:00 Am would be represented as 110000 and you can use simple | operation on all numbers.

Time O(n) Memory O(12n) byte. It would be way faster theoretically.

---

Given a Meeting [start time in minute, end time in minute].

Merging two meetings (Sa & Sb) into Sc when overlapping

Sc [ minimum (SA-start, SB-start), maximum (SA-end, SB-end) ] and storing merged meetings in collection. If not overlapping then you can store them separately.

We know that total minutes in a day = 24 * 60 = 1440
If you have 15 minute unit then it becomes 24 * 60 / 15 = 96 (under 1 byte)

So you need 2 byte per schedule i.e. byte start, end.

Time O(n) Memory O(2n) byte

---

Both approach won't work if you have to delete a meeting later. For that you would definitely to hold all original meeting schedule separately.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's unrealistic to schedule meetings with timeslots less than 15 Minutes, I'd settle for ... a `long`. 64 bits per day, that is enough for 16 hours; I don't need that much. Or use two longs / three ints for a full day, if you want.

Merging then is an `|` operation. For larger timeslots, I can shift-or them, then check for unset bits as meeting start times. This highly compressed data structure will kick ass of any index, just because of the low-level operations. The CPU cache can fit the schedules of hundreds of days / users.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating free slots without merging schedules:

- Employee 1 availability(bounds): [9:00 to 20:00]
- Employee 1 busy schedule intervals:
  [[9:00, 10:30],[12:00, 13:00],[16:00, 18:00]]
- Employee 2 availability(bounds) : [10:00 to 18:30]
- Employee 2 busy schedule intervals: [[10:00, 11:30],[12:30,
  14:30],[14:30, 15:00],[16:00, 17:00]]
- Free intervals: [[11:30, 12:00],[15:00, 16:00],[18:00, 18:30]]
- **Program output: [11h:30m - 12h:00m] [15h:00m - 16h:00m] [18h:00m - 18h:30m]**

Here is my approach: I donot merge calenders to calculate free time, instead I use TreeMap to mark busy schedule as 'B' and free time as 'F'.  I take every minute into consideration within lower and upper bound.  Initially, map will be updated with 'F' assuming free time is available for lower to upper bound.  Later, map will be updated with busy schedule. Time complexity is O(n*2) because intervals is a list, each interval needs to be processed to update the map.  Space complexity is O(n).

```
ScheduleFinderTest test = new ScheduleFinderTest();
test.findFreeSchedules();

public class ScheduleFinderTest {

public void findFreeSchedules() {

    // Employee availability time ( 9:00 to 12:00 )
    MeetingIntervals bound = new MeetingIntervals(9, 00, 20, 00);
    MeetingIntervals busyInterval1 = new MeetingIntervals(9, 00, 10, 30);
    MeetingIntervals busyInterval2 = new MeetingIntervals(12, 00, 13, 00);
    MeetingIntervals busyInterval3 = new MeetingIntervals(16, 00, 18, 00);
    List<MeetingIntervals> allBusyIntervals1 = Arrays.asList(busyInterval1, busyInterval2, busyInterval3);      
    Employee e1 = new Employee("John", bound, allBusyIntervals1);

    // Employee availability time ( 10:00 to 18:30 )
    bound = new MeetingIntervals(10, 00, 18, 30); 
    busyInterval1 = new MeetingIntervals(10, 00, 11, 30);
    busyInterval2 = new MeetingIntervals(12, 30, 14, 30);
    busyInterval3 = new MeetingIntervals(14, 30, 15, 00);
    MeetingIntervals busyInterval4 = new MeetingIntervals(16, 00, 17, 00);
    List<MeetingIntervals> allBusyIntervals2 = Arrays.asList(busyInterval1, busyInterval2, busyInterval3, busyInterval4);
    Employee e2 = new Employee("Christiana", bound, allBusyIntervals2);

    ScheduleFinder scheduleFinder = new ScheduleFinder(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
    scheduleFinder.find();
   } 
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Employee {
   private String name; 
   private MeetingIntervals bounds;
   private List<MeetingIntervals> intervals;    
 }

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class MeetingIntervals {
   private int fromHour;
   private int fromMinutes;
   private int toHour;
   private int toMinutes;
 }

public class ScheduleFinder {

private List<Employee> employees;

public ScheduleFinder(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}

public void find() {

    // sort all bound hours (from availability)  and get the maximum one
    Collections.sort(employees, (e1, e2) -> e2.getBounds().getFromHour() - e1.getBounds().getFromHour());
    int inTimeHour = employees.get(0).getBounds().getFromHour();
    int inTimeMinutes = employees.get(0).getBounds().getFromMinutes();

    // sort all bound hours ( to availability ) and get the minimum one
    Collections.sort(employees, (e1, e2)-> e1.getBounds().getToHour() - e2.getBounds().getToHour());
    int exitTimeHour = employees.get(0).getBounds().getToHour();
    int exitTimeMinutes = employees.get(0).getBounds().getToMinutes();

    // initially mark the map with free time for bounds as calculated above
    MeetingIntervals availableInterval = new MeetingIntervals(inTimeHour, inTimeMinutes, exitTimeHour, exitTimeMinutes);        
    Map<String, Character> scheduleMap = new TreeMap<>();
    updateSchedule(availableInterval, scheduleMap, 'F');
    System.out.println(scheduleMap);

    // update the map with busy intervals
    List<MeetingIntervals> allBusyIntervals = employees.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.getIntervals().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());      
    Collections.sort(allBusyIntervals, (e1, e2) -> e1.getFromHour() - e2.getFromHour());        
    updateScheduleMap(allBusyIntervals, scheduleMap, 'B');
    System.out.println(scheduleMap);

    // print free schedules
    printFreeSchedules(scheduleMap, exitTimeHour, exitTimeMinutes);                     
}

private void updateScheduleMap(List<MeetingIntervals> busyIntervals, Map<String, Character> scheduleMap, char marker) {

    for (MeetingIntervals interval : busyIntervals) {
        updateSchedule(interval, scheduleMap, marker);
    }
}

private void updateSchedule(MeetingIntervals interval, Map<String, Character> map, char marker) {

    int startTimeHour = interval.getFromHour();
    int startTimeMinutes = interval.getFromMinutes();

    int startTimeInMinutes = getTimeInMinutes( startTimeHour, startTimeMinutes); 
    int endTimeInMinutes = getTimeInMinutes( interval.getToHour(), interval.getToMinutes());        

    for (int i = 0; i < (endTimeInMinutes - startTimeInMinutes); i++) {

        String key = getFormattedKey(startTimeHour, startTimeMinutes);

        if (marker == 'B' && map.get(key) != null) {
            map.put(key, marker);               
        } else if (marker == 'F' && map.get(key) == null) {
            map.put(key, marker);
        }

        ++startTimeMinutes;

        if (startTimeMinutes == 60) {
            startTimeMinutes = 0;
            ++startTimeHour;
        }
    }       
}

private int getTimeInMinutes(int hour, int minutes) {
    return ( hour * 60 ) + minutes ;    
}

public String getFormattedKey(int hour, int minutes) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String hourStr = hour + "";
    String minutesStr = minutes + "";

    if (String.valueOf(hour).length() == 1) {
        hourStr = "0" + hour;       
    }

    if (String.valueOf(minutes).length() == 1) {
        minutesStr = "0" + minutes;
    }   

    sb.append(hourStr).append("h:").append(minutesStr).append("m");
    return sb.toString();
}

private void printFreeSchedules(Map<String, Character> scheduleMap, int exitTimeHour, int exitTimeMinutes) {
    boolean intervalStarted = false;
    boolean intervalEnded = false;

    for(String k : scheduleMap.keySet()) {

        if ( scheduleMap.get(k) == 'F' && intervalStarted == false) {
            System.out.print("[" + k);
            intervalStarted = true;
            intervalEnded = false;
        }

        if ( scheduleMap.get(k) == 'B' && intervalStarted == true && intervalEnded == false) {
            System.out.println(" - " + k + "]");
            intervalEnded = true;
            intervalStarted = false;
        }
    }

    if ( intervalStarted == true && intervalEnded == false ) {
        System.out.println(" - " + exitTimeHour + "h:" + exitTimeMinutes + "m]");
      }
    }       
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic problem of [Task Scheduling](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/computer-science/threads/106011).